# How can I get around ffmpeg with python Permission Denied?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub, audiosegment

I am trying to get raw data from an mp3 file with python. I know there are easy ways to do this with a wave file, but I don't want to convert it. This is the relevant part of my code:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
```

```
AudioSegment.converter = "C:/Program Files/Ffmpeg"
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "C:/Program Files/Ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe"
```

```
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3("audio/" + song_box.get(ANCHOR))
```

When it gets to that last line, it returns an error "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied."

I had previous errors, so I figured out I needed to install ffmpeg, and I got that set up in it's own folder (see in the code) and I also put it on both the user path and the system path (system? whatever the main one is). I also bypassed the  folder C:/Program Files/Ffmpeg in windows defender, but that did not help. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Looks like you need to own that file to get the audio.  `chmod` on it before trying again.

Comment: I'm on windows 10, I just tried using takeown and also icacls with no success